# Postgresql Error: connection terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql-9.3

i have a simple application linked up to a postgres database. it reads about 30 rows of data when you load up the application. but every now an then it wont load and when i look at my server i have the error Error: connection terminated.

usually if i load it up several times in a short space of time.

does anyone know why this might be happening? am i working it too hard?

the code is below:

```
    function getDB(callback){
        console.log('inside getDB')
        Client.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                return console.log('connection error', err)
            }
            Client.query('SELECT * FROM gallery', function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    return console.log('error receiving data', err)
                } else{
                callback(null, result.rows)
                }
                Client.end()
            })

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into the same "**Error: Connection terminated**" error on a Node method that was inserting rows into a Postgres database.  Here's how I was able to fix it.

The console error was not very helpful, so I looked at the Postgres logs. (using a Mac)

```
$ tail -10 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log 
2019-02-24 10:06:38.920 CST [58520] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2019-02-24 10:06:38.921 CST [58520] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
```

This means that the client somehow dropped the connection before the server could finish.  In my case, I did not call my asynchronous methods correctly so the client finished before the database statement could be executed and client dropped the DB connection.  I used the async/await style Node methods and I forgot to call my async method with await, which caused the error.

Be sure to follow one of these [examples](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) for Postgres queries in Node.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). You should consider using its connection pooling. From the documentation:

> "Generally you will access the PostgreSQL server through a pool of
>   clients. A client takes a non-trivial amount of time to establish a
>   new connection. A client also consumes a non-trivial amount of
>   resources on the PostgreSQL server - not something you want to do on
>   every http request. Good news: node-postgres ships with built in
>   client pooling."

There is a lot going on when creating a new connection and you should look to avoid it when possible. Taking advantage of pooling could help in your situation.